# Different behavior of <filesystem> in VS2013 vs. VS2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, std

I'm getting different behavior between VS2012 Update 4 and VS2013 Update 1 in this test program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::tr2::sys;

void main()
{
  string s("C:\\");

  for (auto i = directory_iterator(path(s).parent_path()); i != directory_iterator(); ++i) 
    cout << (path(s).parent_path()/i->path()).string() << endl;
}
```

VS2012 produces:

```
C:AUTOEXEC.BAT
...
```

VS2013 produces:

```
C:C:AUTOEXEC.BAT
...
```

Which behavior conforms with C++ standard?

**EDIT**

Since `filesystem` is not yet in C++ standard, but is only a [library proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3505.html), I rephrase my question: is VS2013 behavior a bug?

Comment: The standard doesn't include `filesystem` (yet, anyway) so neither is particularly more or less compliant (though the `C:C:` certainly looks like a bug--I can't imagine it's intended behavior).

Comment: In addition to Jerry Coffin's comment, the future standard filesystem library would more or less be based on [`Boost.Filesystem`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) (VS's is also based on it), which provides a more stable and more documented API than VS's. However, as I have experienced, it still doesn't support VS 2013 (as it depends on some other Boost components that also doesn't), which throws out compile errors when being built and built-with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this was a bug in VC++ 2012. Here's an excerpt from [C++11/14 STL Features, Fixes, And Breaking Changes In VS 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/06/28/c-11-14-stl-features-fixes-and-breaking-changes-in-vs-2013.aspx).

> <filesystem>'s directory_iterator was returning paths that were too
>   short (DevDiv#411531).  (Note that recursive_directory_iterator worked
>   correctly.)  We fixed directory_iterator to follow N1975, the
>   Filesystem V2 draft.  (Filesystem V3 is on our radar, but it won't be
>   implemented in 2013 RTM.)

You can find [N1975 here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n1975.html).

Comment: That sounds familiar: I vaguely remember being puzzled by different behavior of `recursive_directory_iterator` compared to `directory_iterator` with VS2012 and unnecessary complexity to get a simple file path.